# typeORM postgres don't seem to find database

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I'm using windows 10, Nest.js and typeORM.
Previously, I had to create a new user\role uder my windows user - but now the ORM don't seem to find my db (called steamClone) - and calls a db named after my user:

```
error: database "Itay" does not exist
```

typeORM is configured like such encapsulated in a module:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import {ConfigModule, ConfigService} from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
            imports: [ConfigModule],
            inject: [ConfigService],
            useFactory: (ConfigService: ConfigService) => ({
                type: 'postgres',
                host: ConfigService.get('DB_HOST'),
                port: ConfigService.get('DB_PORT'),
                username: ConfigService.get('DB_USER'),
                password: ConfigService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
                database: ConfigService.get('DB_DATABASE'),
                entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
                synchronize: true,
            })
        })
    ],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

all of the parameters are stored in a .env file
running on localhost, default port and everything, postgres user etc.

would love to know how to solve this